# assetLinks.json file problem while configuring App Links in Android

Tags: android, linux, hyperlink, dns, applinks

I am trying to configure App Links in my Android app.

Android documentation says I need to have   mydomain/.well-known/assetLinks.json file in place.

The problem is, my hosting provider (Domain.com) does not allow directories (files) starting with a dot.

I talked to their tech support and they say "our system architecture does not allow it"

Since they are running on Linux, I assume it's not true, but they seem unwilling to help.

Is there anything I can do, or am I in a hopeless situation?